# Is there any way how can I create Elasticsearch Search Template from BoolQueryBuilder directly?

Tags: java, templates, elasticsearch

How can I easily create Search Template from BoolQueryBuilder in Java ?

Right now I am trying to do it like this, but this solution seems a little bit dirty to me. Is there any better way ?

```
BoolQueryBuilder boolQueryBuilder = new BoolQueryBuilder();
boolQueryBuilder.must(new MoreLikeThisQueryBuilder("myField", "{{myTextToBeReplaced}}", null));
SearchResponse response = new SearchTemplateRequestBuilder(client)
        .setRequest(new SearchRequest())
        .setScriptType(ScriptType.INLINE)
        .setScript(boolQueryBuilder.toString())
        .setScriptParams(templateParams)
        .get();
```

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0):

You are executing inline templates, and you´re even using boolQueryBuilder.toString() to render the json instead of messy string concatenation. Good work so far @Druudik.

But have you tried **stored templates at search time** (https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html) ?
This will move the templating completely out of your java code! Especially for larger queries this approach reduces the code complexity.

This will also make your appliaction more flexible, as you'll be able to change the query/template, without recompiling your code (as long your parameters are stable).

Here are some examples using java api: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/current/java-search-template.html